# debian не может включиться по умолчанию

Tags: debian, загрузка, grub, bios, dell

я поставил дебиан. когда я пытался войти,меня кидало в grub rescue. сейчас я поставил нормальный загрузчик,но тот почему то сохранился. и в итоге я могу войти в debian только через one-time boot menu. там debian находится в UEFI BOOT. вопрос таков:как настроить bios,чтобы он грузил debian по умолчанию?
ноутбук dell inspiron 5567,dell bios соответственно. пробовал искать в настройках биос,не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Если совсем просто, то:

1. Проверить что загрузчик жив, утилитой Boot Repair
2. Настроить загрузчик как хочется, утилитой Grub Customizer